Shopify REST API adjusting InventoryLevel doesn't works
I am building an job that interacts with Shopify API with shopify-api-ruby gem, here the test code:
LOCATION_ID = '61167763535'
VARIANT_ID = '41932294357071'

variant = ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(id: VARIANT_ID)
inventory_item = ShopifyAPI::InventoryItem.find(id: variant.inventory_item_id)
inventory_level = ShopifyAPI::InventoryLevel.all(inventory_item_ids: inventory_item.id.to_s, location_ids: '61167763535').first

inventory_level.adjust(inventory_item_id: inventory_item.id, location_id: LOCATION_ID, available_adjustment: 10)

It fetches variant, inventory_item for this variant, and then inventory_level for that variant, and all is going perfect till when I am trying to adjust inventory_level and got an error:
{"errors":"Not Found","error_reference":"If you report this error, please include this id: cdbae146-8541-4b99-ade1-631b793ea6ff-1723807714."}

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, I trying several a bit another approaches described here - https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2024-04/resources/inventorylevel#post-inventory-levels-adjust, but I got same error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix that?

API documentation method params and shared code params are not the same, did you try the documentation style as well? https://prnt.sc/lgDYGzDSCvPA

@Onkar, yes, I tried, and it didn't work as well =(
